# Assign a variable in a foreach loop

Tags: perl

I dont really understand how to assign the output of this code to either a variable for each line of output or just one big block variable. Im using Mail::POP3Client if that helps. The output i am looking to assign a variable to is " print "$_\n" if /^(From|Subject):/i;"

```
my $count = $pop->Count();
if ($count < 0) {
    print $pop->Message();
} elsif ($count == 0) {
    print "no messages\n";
} else {
    print "$count messsages\n\n";

    for my $i (1 .. $count) {
        foreach ($pop->Head($i)) {
            print "$_\n" if /^(From|Subject):/i;
        }
        print "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options, depending on how you want to process the data

Define a variable and append successively to it

```
my $from = '';
...
foreach ($pop->Head($i)) {
    $from .= "$_\n" if (/^(From|Subject):/i);
}
```

this will give you a large string with all `From`s and `Subject`s together.
Or you define an array and append to the end of this array

```
my @from;
...
foreach ($pop->Head($i)) {
    push @from, $_ if (/^(From|Subject):/i);
}
```

this will result in an array, where each element contains one `From` or `Subject` line.

According to [Mail::POP3Client](http://search.cpan.org/~sdowd/Mail-POP3Client-2.16/POP3Client.pm), if you want to delete all messages on the POP server

```
for my $i (1 .. $count) {
    $pop->Delete($i);
}
```

*before* close should mark all messages for deletion. When you finally close the connection,

```
$pop->Close();
```

all pending deletes will be processed.

Comment: the single variable seems to work better for my case. Do you have any idea how i would delete all messages after this script is ran in CPAN the syntax is Delete( MESSAGE_NUMBER ) but not sure how to apply this.

Answer (score 2):

Make an array beforehand, called, say, `@mystuff`. Instead of `print "$_\n" if /^(From|Subject):/i;`, make it `push(@mystuff, $_) if /^(From|Subject):/i;`. At the end you have an array of the things currently being printed in the foreach.